# How to display detail objects after filtering their primary object in django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views, django-template-filters

I am working on an app that can create teams, Players,I am now on displaying player objects which are connected by a foreign key teams that displays relevant players to their team.But the problem I am getting is when the player objects are displayed in detail view,all the players get displayed while that specific player objects should be displayed.Please help me to solve the problem.

here,s the html

```
    {% include 'games_app/base.html' %}
    {% block body_block %}

<div>
    {% for players in play.teams.all %}
    <h1>Players :<strong>{{players.player_name}}</strong></h1>
    <h1>Players-age :<strong>{{players.player_age}}</strong></h1>
    <h1>Players-form :<strong>{{players.player_form}}</strong></h1>
    <h1>Players-over :<strong>{{players.over}}</strong></h1>
    <h1>Players-batting :<strong>{{players.batting}}</strong></h1>
    <a href="{% url 'games_app:players_update' players.pk %}">Edit Player</a></br>
    <a href="{% url 'games_app:players_delete' players.pk %}">Delete Player</a>
    {% endfor %}
</div>

    {% endblock %}
```

Here,s the views.py of detail players

```
def Detail_Players(request,pk):

    model = models.Team.objects.get(pk=True)

    template_name = 'games_app/players_detail.html'


    return render(request, template_name, context=model)
```

[SOLVED] I just changed the model and other details.

Answer (score 1):

You should try this:

```py
model = models.Team.objects.get(pk=pk)
```

And then pass the context to the template in the correct way.

Comment: what do you mean by setting the context in a correct way

Comment: after doing what you said i get Team matching query does not exist.

Comment: So you want a pk that does not exist in your DB.

Comment: You want to use play.teams.all but does not declare in your view

Comment: It exists but i don't know why it gives me this error

Comment: Do you have a Team with requested PK?

Comment: I just solved the problem by setting the model to Players and then displaying the data , It was a foolish mistake yet so tricky. :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are setting pk to True instead of pk.

```
model = models.Team.objects.get(pk=True)
```

should be

```
model = models.Team.objects.get(pk=pk)
```

Comment: i get an error then Team matching query does not exist.

Comment: I just solved the problem by setting the model to Players and then displaying the data , It was a foolish mistake yet so tricky. :)

Answer (score 0):

in views.py there is simplest way to create your detailview as following:

```
from django.views import generic
class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Team
    template_name = 'games_app/players_detail.html'
```

then in urls.py Pk should be passed as avariable to determine to which player you want to go:

```
path('<pk>/detail', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
```

then in your template use method "set" through your for loop as follows:

```
 {% for player in team.player_set.all %}
....
```